# Is there a way we can conncet mulesoft and unix to retrive files from unix server and send via email

Tags: unix, mulesoft

Can someone provide some guidance on ho we can connect mulesoft and a unix server to retrieve  files from unix server and send the file or share the location of the file via mulesoft.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

MulesSoft Is a company. I'll assume that you mean to use MuleSoft's Mule runtime and create a Mule application to implement the integration described. First determine what protocols the Unix server allows to access files. Usually it would be SFTP but it could be the insecure FTP or even HTTP. Assuming HTTP, you can use the SFTP connector listener to poll periodically for files to appear. Then use the Email connector to send the body of the file read in the previous step as an attachment.

Alternatively you could use the list files operation to read the files names and use that information to just send the locations in the email.

You can find more information about the operations in the documentation.

Documentation:

- https://docs.mulesoft.com/sftp-connector/1.4/
- https://docs.mulesoft.com/email-connector/1.4/

Comment: but how can we connect  mule runtime to unix server via generic login  id .

Comment: I'm not quite sure what do you mean by generic login. An SFTP or FTP server in Unix/Linux usually uses user ids to authorize access. If you are referring to accessing through a terminal, then you will need to expand your question to provide more details on what kind of integration you are trying to implement. It sounds like you might be trying to automate a process by executing commands in the server, rather than implement some kind of integration.

Comment: Yeah true , i am trying to automate a process via mulesoft . The ideologu behind the  POC is using mule runtime , i need to connect to a unix server . There will be  files  present in the server ,i need to pick the files from the server and send the file as a  mail or share the location , so that as a person outside of my organisation can acess it

Comment: That process can be automated as I described in my answer. You need to find out what services/protocols the server allows to query and pick up the files. Usually SFTP is used, but your server might allow something different. You need to get the right credentials for that and also the email server.

Comment: I added more details to the answer